# How to prove this identity? $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{{n + \alpha - 1}\choose{n}}z^n.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, binomial-coefficients

In this thread, [General formula for the power series of $\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437309/general-formula-for-the-power-series-of-dfrac11x3/3437313#3437313)

the_candyman posted an identity:

$$(1-z)^{-\alpha} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{{n + \alpha - 1}\choose{n}}z^n.$$

Notice that this binomial series has a negative exponent. I know that the general formula for binomial series is:

$$(1+x)^k=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\binom{k}{n}}x^n$$.

How do apply the second definition to prove the first identity?

Comment: Try using the binomial series and the [negative binomial identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522045/how-do-i-prove-the-negative-binomial-identity).

Comment: Put $x=z, k=-\alpha$ and expand the binomial coefficients in full and you will see the identity $$(-1)^n\binom{-\alpha}{n}=\binom{n+\alpha - 1}{n}$$ in a very obvious manner.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh $\binom{n+k-1}{n}=\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n+k-1-k)}=\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n+1)!}$, is this correct, how can I simplify this further to give the right hand side?

Comment: You need to expand in full like $$(-1)^n\binom{-\alpha}{n}=(-1)^n\frac{(-\alpha)(-\alpha-1)\dots(-\alpha-n+1)}{n!}$$ and then you get desired result.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Can you do this in full steps so I can learn, you can answer my question and I will mark your answer. This way you can earn a few points. Sorry, I haven't mastered the binomial notation yet so I am kind of slow.

Comment: There are no further steps. Just note that $(-1)^n$ is used to change signs of all the $n$ factors in denominator to get $$\frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)\dots(\alpha+n-1)}{n!}$$ and this is $$\binom{n+\alpha-1}{n}$$

Comment: The definition of binomial coefficient is $$\binom{a} {n} =\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)\dots(a-(n-1))}{n!}$$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use  the following definition  of  binomial  identities valid  for complex $\alpha$ and non-negative integers  $n$:
\begin{align*}
\binom{\alpha}{n}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
which can be  found for instance as formula (5.1)  in *[Concrete  Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* 
 by   R.L.  Graham, D.E. Knuth   and O. Patashnik.

> We   obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\binom{n+\alpha-1}{n}}&=\frac{(n+\alpha-1)((n+\alpha-1)-1)\cdots(n+\alpha-1-(n-1))}{n!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{(n+\alpha-1)((n+\alpha-2)\cdots\alpha}{n!}\\
> &=(-1)^n\frac{(-\alpha)(-\alpha-1)\cdots(-\alpha-(n-1))}{n!}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^n\binom{-\alpha}{n}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In  (2) we use the definition (1).
- In (3) we factor out $(-1)^n$.
- In (4) we use the definition (1) again.

> From  (2) and (4) we conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> (1-z)^{-\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-\alpha}{n}(-z)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+\alpha-1}{n}z^n\qquad\qquad |z|<1
> \end{align*}